# When does upgrading require a restart or disruption of services?

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, upgrade

I'm using google compute engine with a single VM instance (machine type: e2-custom-2-5632/skylake) that needs an upgrade. Services are bumping up against limits and throttling. I'm trying to purchase a committed use discount and upgrade the VM with additional RAM/memory without taking down all wordpress websites running on centOS.

Similar questions I've searched for Google Community Forums:

When does upgrading cause my services to stop or require a restart?
Which upgrades require a restart?
Do commitment use discounts require restarting services?
If I upgrade VM ram do I have to restart services?
If I follow a recommendation and upgrade via commitment use discount do I have to restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

> When does upgrading cause my services to stop or require a restart?

Changing CPU, memory, storage and configuration requires shutting down the VM first.

> Which upgrades require a restart?

Changing CPU, memory, storage and configuration requires shutting down the VM first.

> Do commitment use discounts require restarting services?

Committed use discounts are applied to the billing statement and do not affect individual virtual machines.

> If I upgrade VM ram do I have to restart services?

Yes.

> If I follow a recommendation and upgrade via commitment use discount
> do I have to restart the server?

Committed use discounts do not upgrade virtual machines, they only change pricing of existing virtual machines.

Comment: John, you're a rockstar, many many thanks for reducing my fear. I'll do some upgrading tonight and reply back with any useful experience data. Thank you!